# Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PRMAUD_PROJRISK, Line 24 Invalid column name 'wbs_id'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error :Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PRMAUD_PROJRISK, Line 24
Invalid column name 'wbs_id'. when I run the following stored proc

```
 DECLARE RiskCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT risk_id, risk_desc from PROJRISK
OPEN RiskCursor
DECLARE @riskID INT, @HTMLText VARCHAR(4000), @Start INT, @End INT, @Length INT
FETCH NEXT FROM RiskCursor INTO @riskID, @HTMLText
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
  END
SET @HTMLText = LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
UPDATE PROJRISK SET risk_desc = @HTMLText where risk_id = @riskID 
FETCH NEXT FROM RiskCursor INTO @riskID, @HTMLText 
 END
 CLOSE RiskCursor
 DEALLOCATE RiskCursor
 GO
 go
```

Please help in resolving the errors

Comment: I don't see 'wbs_id' anywhere in that cursor so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: please post code for complete procedure PRMAUD_PROJRISK to help you better.IS it like you get above error when running posted adhoc query?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information supplied, you've probably got an invalid trigger on the `projrisk` table.